# Error in returning dictionary items as string? (python)

Tags: python, class, dictionary, syntax

I have a class that has an empty dictionary attribute:

```
class Library:
    def __init__(self,library):
        self.library={}
    
    def addSong(self,title,artist,genre,playCount):
        for i in self.library.keys():
            if i == title:
                x=self.library.get(title)
                x[2]= x[2]+1
            else:    
                self.library[title]=[artist,genre,playCount]
    
    def song2String(self,title):
        x=self.library.get(title)
        return f"{x[0]} {title} ({x[1]}), {x[2]}"
```

Now when I do this:

```
m1= Library({})
m1.addSong("Saturday Night's Alright for Fighting","Elton John","Rock",22)
```

The code runs properly and items are added to the `m1` dictionary.
But when I type this:

```
print(m1.song2String("Saturday Night's Alright for Fighting"))
```

I get this error message:

```
return f"str{x[0]} str{title} (str{x[1]}), str{x[2]}" 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

What is my syntax error?

Comment: `self.library.get(title)` is returning `None`, which would either indicate that `title` is not a key in `self.library`, or that the value at `self.library[title]` is `None`.

Comment: Sure to add +1 and not +playcount ?, like when calling with 22 twice, should be 23 or 44 ?

Comment: "The code runs properly and items are added to the m1 dictionary." *are you sure*? How do you know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You iterate on the `library` keys : `for i in self.library.keys()`, but as there is none, nothing is done, the minimal change to make it work is

```
def addSong(self, title, artist, genre, playCount):
    for i in self.library.keys():
        if i == title:
            x = self.library.get(title)
            x[2] = x[2] + 1
            break
    else:
        self.library[title] = [artist, genre, playCount]
```

But the best is just to test if the title is present, then do the right thing.

```
def addSong(self, title, artist, genre, playCount):
    if title in self.library:
        self.library[title][2] += playCount
    else:
        self.library[title] = [artist, genre, playCount]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code return None, this is the cause of your error. I am not sure why you looped over the keys to insert your song, just use the dictionary directly:

```
class Library:
    def __init__(self,library):
        self.library={}
    
    def addSong(self,title,artist,genre,playCount):
        if title in self.library:   ## changed code here and below
            x=self.library.get(title)
            x[2]= x[2]+1
        else:    
            self.library[title]=[artist,genre,playCount]
    
    def song2String(self,title):
        x=self.library.get(title)
        return f"{x[0]} {title} ({x[1]}), {x[2]}"
```

output:

```
m1= Library({})
m1.addSong("Saturday Night's Alright for Fighting","Elton John","Rock",22)
print(m1.library)
# {"Saturday Night's Alright for Fighting": ['Elton John', 'Rock', 22]}

print(m1.song2String("Saturday Night's Alright for Fighting"))
# Elton John Saturday Night's Alright for Fighting (Rock), 22
```

Answer (score 0):

> I Suppose this is what you expected. In here In addsong function,
> first I check is any keys available the dictionary. If it is true,
> iterate and do what you want. otherwise, add the first dictionary item
> to the dictionary. Inside the songs2string method, first you want to
> identify how a dictionary works. In this case, key is a string and the
> value is list in the dictionary. So then You can return what you want
> using a dictionary.

```
class Library:
    def __init__(self,library=dict()):
        self.library=library
    
    def addSong(self,title,artist,genre,playCount):
        
        if len(self.library.keys())>0:
            for i in self.library.keys():
                if i == title:
                    x=self.library.get(title)
                    x[2]= x[2]+1
        else:    
            self.library[title]=[artist,genre,playCount]
            # print(self.library)
    
    def song2String(self,title):
        x=self.library
        print(x)
        return x[title][0], x[title][1], x[title][2]
    
m1= Library()
m1.addSong("Saturday Night's Alright for Fighting","Elton John","Rock",22)
print(m1.song2String("Saturday Night's Alright for Fighting"))
```